# Using Pandas to read an undelimited file

Tags: python, pandas

I've received an undelimited data file—the data looks like this:

```
$ head usa_00002.dat
20120500000001000000200010001000000200021111147870057729
20120500000001000000200010002000000160022101010000000000
20120500000001000000200010003000000130002010160000999999
20120500000001000000200010004000000200001010120000999999
20120500000002000000240010001000000240001111146870075959
```

I have a codebook file that explains how the data is actually set up (`YEAR columns 1–4, DATANUM columns 5–6` etc)

What is the best way for me to get this data into Pandas? Is there a standard way I could use `read_table` or some similar function to read this file directly? Should I write a script to insert commas where all the column breaks are and then read it in as CSV? (I'd just do the latter, but I'm also interested in becoming better with Pandas so if there's an out-of-the-box way I'd like to know it.)

Comment: Have you already had a look at the docs for [`pd.read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf.html#pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf.html#pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf) function for this:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

s = """20120500000001000000200010001000000200021111147870057729
       20120500000001000000200010002000000160022101010000000000
       20120500000001000000200010003000000130002010160000999999
       20120500000001000000200010004000000200001010120000999999
       20120500000002000000240010001000000240001111146870075959"""

colspecs = [(0, 4), (5, 6), ...]
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(s), colspecs=colspecs, header=None)
```